# Adding 3rd Party JAR to Spring Boot War Build intended for a remote Server

Tags: spring-boot, maven, tomcat, maven-surefire-plugin

I am converting a local Spring boot Jar app to a War build , using an external TomCat server.

Spring Boot app is running using 2 3rd party jars placed in libs folder.

I am facing an issue trying to include these 2 jars to the final war.

Added these jars to the ClassPath intelliJ Artifact settings but no luck.
Tried putting them manually in WEB-INF/lib folder but no luck.

Tried the above method.

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>myJarGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>myJarArtifact</artifactId>
        <version>>1.7.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xxx/myjar.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Again no luck.
WEB-INF/lib is still missing my 2 jars.

```
Only a type can be imported. ec.ec.ada.ec.common.ec.code.testValidate resolves to a package

    testValidate cannot be resolved
Error importing : 'ec.ec.ada.ec.common.ec.code.testValidate'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to incluse these two jars as dependency in pom. I know this is 3rd party depencdency but you can add it like below:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///path/to/yourproject/repo/ -Dfile=mylib-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=mylib -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0
```

This way they will be saved in maven repository and maven war plugin will include same in war that will be generated for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

> Although rarely, but sometimes you will have 3rd party JARs that you
>   need to put in your local repository for use in your builds, since
>   they don't exist in any public repository like Maven Central. The JARs
>   must be placed in the local repository in the correct place in order
>   for it to be correctly picked up by Apache Maven. To make this easier,
>   and less error prone, we have provide a goal in the
>   maven-install-plugin which should make this relatively painless. To
>   install a JAR in the local repository use the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
 -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

> With version 2.5 of the maven-install-plugin it gets even better. If
>   the JAR was built by Apache Maven, it'll contain a pom.xml in a
>   subfolder of the META-INF directory, which will be read by default. In
>   that case, all you need to do is:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```

From a [Maven Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).